# Teradata Date calculation format issue

Tags: date, format, teradata, date-format, calculation

I have this date set uploaded from SAS to TD and the date format is like MEDI_START_DT format,'MM/DD/YYYY' 
And now I want to make a calculation baesed on this column
MEDI_START_DT  + PDAYSSUP -1 = MEDI_END_DT_PRE
but MEDI_END_DT_PRE's format is not a date and I tried cast(MEDI_END_DT_PRE's as date) and it says invalid date.
Do you guys have any idea on how to get a date format result after the calculation? Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i64NV.png)

Comment: If MEDI_START_DT is a DATE variable and PDAYSSUP is an integer then your expression should evaluate automatically as a DATE.

Answer (score 0):

If you loaded the data from SAS and it was formatted as a DATE in SAS then it should work.  You should check if your `PDAYSSUP` variable got defined as `FLOAT` in Teradata.  Try casting that variable:

```
select MEDI_START_DT + cast(PDAYSSUP as integer) -1 as MEDI_END_DT_PRE
from ...
```

Comment: The problem was we should change 'int' to 'integer' otherwise it wont work. Thank you for your answer! :)

Comment: THanks. Fixed the answer to spell out the type name.